# Anonymous text block width for inline-block elements

Tags: html, css

I am trying to make the width of a container div dynamically collapse onto its inline-block contents.  From what I can determine this is imposible per [9.4.2 Inline formatting contexts](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#inline-formatting)

> In general, the left edge of a line box touches the left edge of its containing block and the right edge touches the right edge of its containing block. However, floating boxes may come between the containing block edge and the line box edge. Thus, although line boxes in the same inline formatting context generally have the same width (that of the containing block), they may vary in width if available horizontal space is reduced due to floats.

The problem is the anonymous text blocks assume the width of their container.

I want the internal elements to respond to width like this...

```js
var demoContainer = d3.select('#demoContainer').style('width', '200px');
function tick() {
 demoContainer.transition().duration(3000).style('width', '300px')
 .transition().duration(2000).style('width', '300px')
 .transition().duration(3000).style('width', '550px')
 .transition().duration(3000).style('width', '300px')
 .transition().duration(2000).style('width', '300px')
 .transition().duration(3000).style('width', '100px')
 .each('end', tick);
};
tick();
```

```css
#htmlDiv {
      font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, 'Segoe UI', Arial, freesans, sans-serif;
      font-size: 12px;
      outline: solid 1px black;
      background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.25);
      display: inline-block;
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    .container,
    #bubble-wrapper {
      height: auto;
      position: relative;
      display: inline-block;
      margin: 5px;
      background-color: rgba(0, 38, 255, 0.25);
      outline: solid 1px white;
      text-align: left;
    }

    .bubbles {
      color: #ccc;
    }

    .select-bubbles,
    .bubbles {
      padding: 5px;
      margin: 5px;
      outline: solid 1px white;
      background-color: rgb(114, 114, 114);
      width: 100px;
      display: inline-block;
    }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.4.11/d3.min.js"></script>
<div id="demoContainer" style="outline: solid 3px red; padding: 10px">
    <div id="htmlDiv">
      <div class="container">
        display: inline-block;
        <br>position: relative;
        <br />
        <div class="select-bubbles">
          inline-block
        </div>
      </div>
      <br>
      <div id="bubble-wrapper">
        display: inline-block;
        <br>position: relative;
        <br>
        <div class="bubbles bubble1">
          inline-block
        </div>
        <div class="bubbles bubble2">
          inline-block
        </div>
        <div class="bubbles bubble2">
          inline-block
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

But I need the container to shrink-wrap the inner divs...

this is fine
[image]
and so is this
[image]
but this is not what I'm looking for...
[image]

Have I correctly understood the spec and if so is there a way to achieve what I'm looking for?

**UPDATE**
As pointed out by @Alohci the more important reference is

[10.3.9 'Inline-block', non-replaced elements in normal flow](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visudet.html#inlineblock-width)

> If 'width' is 'auto', the used value is the shrink-to-fit width as for
>   floating elements.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've correctly understood the consequence of the spec, though IMHO you've not quoted the critical part. That's the [shrink-to-fit algorithm](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visudet.html#shrink-to-fit-float), which says:

> ... calculate the preferred width by formatting the content without
>   breaking lines other than where explicit line breaks occur, and also
>   calculate the preferred minimum width, e.g., by trying all possible
>   line breaks. ... Thirdly, find the available width: in this case, this
>   is the width of the containing block minus the used values of
>   'margin-left', 'border-left-width', 'padding-left', 'padding-right',
>   'border-right-width', 'margin-right', and the widths of any relevant
>   scroll bars.
>
> Then the shrink-to-fit width is: min(max(preferred minimum width,
>   available width), preferred width).

Which resolves to the available width, not the minimum width for your "can't shrink wrap" case.

Unfortunately, CSS uses this algorithm widely, so alternative layouts like floating the boxes, have the same problem.

Comment: So by the way, does that mean that its not possible to do what I'm asking?

Answer (score 0):

It`s not perfect but you could work whit this: [fiddle](http://fiddle.jshell.net/4rdc944a/)

Add this to your CSS:

```
#htmlDiv * { box-sizing: border-box; }
```

That property inluded padding and border in the element's total width.

Comment: Well, in my example, the third image that you put don't appears, only all divs in horizontal or all divs in vertical. Sorry if it's I don't understand good and not what you wanted